# How do you remove a table COMMENT in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, comments

We have a MySQL table that was altered with

```
ALTER TABLE t COMMENT 'foo'
```

we later realize that we don't want that comment. Is there a way to delete it?

simply saying

```
ALTER TABLE t COMMENT 'NOT foo'
```

simply adds an additional comment, so that when you do a SHOW CREATE TABLE t it shows BOTH comments...

ETA:

AH,  the problem seems to be that My PHP that is working with the comment can't tell the difference between a comment from an ADD COLUMN and a comment which is just about the whole table...

So, now what I need to do is delete replace the COLUMN comment...

Comment: are you sure about your duplicate comment observation?

Comment: There should be no possibility of two "COMMENT" properties for a single table. `ALTER TABLE t COMMENT 'x'` should replace the current comment with x, not ADD x to the comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ALTER TABLE t COMMENT '';`

should work.

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE test_table COMMENT 'foo';
SHOW CREATE TABLE test_table;
```

results in:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='foo'
```

followed by

```
ALTER TABLE test_table COMMENT '';
SHOW CREATE TABLE test_table;
```

results in:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Depending on the MySQL version an assignment operator may be needed. With MySQL 3.23.58 I had to alter the query to `ALTER TABLE test_table COMMENT='';`.

Answer (score 4):

```
ALTER TABLE t COMMENT ''
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE t COMMENT = ''
```